# Error while creating Unlocked package version with LWC Components

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to create Unlocked package with LWC components. When I do so, I am getting error for naming it in Camel case.

Although, if I change the folder name from 'Notifier' to 'notifier' (without 'N' in caps, it works). Can I never use capital names for my components? or is it a best practice?

```
sfdx force:package:version:create -p notifier -d force-app -k test --wait 10 -v ping.skp-6xj1@force.com
Request in progress. Sleeping 30 seconds. Will wait a total of 600 more seconds before timing out. Current Status='InProgress'
ERROR:  markup://c:Notifier: LWC1116: Illegal folder name "Notifier". The folder name must start with a lowercase character: "notifier".
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Aura Components, the best practice has always been to use `camelCaseNames`. This is now enforced in Lightning Web Components. Note that the `camelCaseName` will be written in `kebab-case` in the template. For example, a `helloWorld` component will be put in a template as `<c-hello-world></c-hello-world>`. This is enforced by the Web Components Standard, and is not specific to LWC. The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_components_folder) specifies a lot of naming rules that must be followed:

> - Must begin with a lowercase letter *(edit: now specifies lowercase)*
> - Must contain only alphanumeric or underscore characters
> - Must be unique in the namespace
> - Can’t include whitespace
> - Can’t end with an underscore
> - Can’t contain two consecutive underscores
> - Can’t contain a hyphen (dash)

And also states:

> Use camel case to name your component `myComponent`. Camel case component folder names map to kebab-case in markup. In markup, to reference a component with the folder name `myComponent`, use `<c-my-component>`.

Comment: I think its again a missing documentation. It would have been good to explicitly specify this as well in the naming rules list something as *Should not start with an uppercase*. You realize this only when you get further in the documentation where it mentions about camelCase for components.

Comment: @JayantDas Even better, they could just have said: *Must begin with an **lowercase** letter*.

Comment: Yeah true. Sometimes you overthink while constructing things :)

Comment: right..makes sense...so its a standard for LWC development

Comment: The docs have been updated.

Comment: @bonehelmet Awesome. I've reflected this edit in my answer.